# Javascript need to keep "selected" option in view

Tags: javascript, html

I have an ordinary select list (single not multiple).  The list is headed by a title such as "Events" :

```
<option selected = "selected" value = " " class = "hselect" > Events </option>
```

Under the title are the actual choices.  The user has a form to fill in, and the Events select box will appear in the form.  Once the user has chosen his event, such as "register", the choice appears in an input box next to the dropdown. I use a Javascript program to do that.

The selection also remains in the select box itself, so that the form shows
|register|  |register|  -- the first in the select box, the second in the input box.  What I need, instead, is for the select box to return itself to the heading, so that the form shows |Events| |register|.

Using the same Javascript program I can pick up the "Events" option, but I don't know how to get the select box to go back to its original configuration with Events showing at the top, and the choices underneath.

Is there a way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: provide code and better a fiddle

Answer (score 3):

To select the first option from a `<select>` use the "selectedIndex" property:

```
var target = document.getElementById('target');
target.onchange=function(){
    alert('select changed!');
    target.selectedIndex = 0;
};
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adriel_santos/n90s0mzm/

Comment: The fiddle looks good -- I'll test it in my own code shortly.  Thx.

Comment: a small change for me, because I was resetting the select box after picking up the new value, not immediately on the change.  So the target.onchange was not needed.  But it's good to learn that option is available.